# Hibernate: sessionFactory.openSession() VS sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a web application in Spring 4(Java Configuration). I am using postgres as database and C3P0 as connection pool.
All my database transactions are happening in postgres stored procedures/ functions. I am using Hibernate @[NamedNativeQueries](http://www.coderanch.com/t/462714/ORM/databases/Calling-Stored-proc-Hibernate-NamedNativeQuery) to call the stored procedures.

I have 2 questions:
 1. My application will have multiple users logged in at same time. SO should i use sessionFactory.openSession() or sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() for getting hibernate session?
 2. shall i use hibernate to call stored procedures or build in support in spring mvc4? i know both ways but i am more comfortable with hibernate as it needs very less efforts compared to spring way but i feel hibernate is making my application slow but not sure.

Please help me in finding answers to these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the first question :
you should have a session per user connected. For example, if you are in a servlet context, you can have a servlet filter to call `sessionFactory.openSession()` per servlet thread.

Answer to the second question :
performance and optimisation is not a feeling. If you `feel` hibernate slow, measure it and try to know why. You have to measure where it slows. You can also try both solutions with a simple example and know where you feel more comfortable.